# CMake, conflicting options with subprojects

Tags: cmake

I've added two libraries to a CMake project, googletest and tinyxml2. I've discovered that they both define the option `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`. Their defaults for the option are also different which results in incorrect builds if not addressed. Currently I need to resort to setting `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)`.

Is there a better way to handle the clash? And is there an option in CMake to detect this clash to ensure it is correctly handled?

Comment: "Is there a better way to handle the clash?" - I know no better way. "Their defaults for the option are also different which results in incorrect builds if not addressed." - If the project defines an **option**, which could be set by a user, it should work with **both** option's settings. So if you want to prefer shared libraries in your project, just set this option to ON **once**: all subprojects should properly handle that setting and do not overwrite it. What do you mean by "incorrect builds"?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, in this case the subprojects build with either option set. The issue I have is that it promotes each **option** to a global scope. It may be that one desires the option to be ON for some libraries and OFF for others. A better example is the `BUILD_TESTS` option used by tinyxml2.

Comment: By "incorrect builds" I simply mean that we do not build as expected.